# Is Close on database connection calling here?

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection, using-statement, devart

I got this code:

```
try
{
    using (OracleConnection c = new OracleConnection(globalDict[byAlias(connAlias)].connString))
    {
        c.Open();

        using (OracleCommand recordExistentQuery = new OracleCommand("regular.IsExistent", c))
        {
        // here working on oraclecommand
        }
    } 
 } catch(Exception exc) { }
```

[OracleConnection](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection.html) is class of devArt dotConnect for Oracle.
Will this code call `c.Close()` when it goes out of `(OracleConnection c = new OracleConnection(globalDict[byAlias(connAlias)].connString)) { .... }` ?

Answer (score 3):

No, it will call `Dipose()`.  A `using` block will implicitly call `Dispose()` on the object specified in the `using` statement.

But often times for a database connection, `Dispose()` handles the `Close()` functionality, releasing the connection/processId that keeps a connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add that in the event of an exception somewhere in your `//here working on oraclecommand` (basically inside your `using(...){ }` statement, `Dispose()` will also be called.

By design, you should be able to make multiple to calls to an object implementing `IDisposable`.  In your case, issuing a calling a call to `Close()` after your `using` block of code will simply do nothing, as the connection has already closed/been returned to the pool.  Any additional calls after the object has cleaned up *should* just return and do nothing.